# Insertar multiples registros en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo el siguiente inconveniente tengo que insertar multiples registros en una tabla llamada checklist, posee 7 campos( 3 int, 3 varchar y 1 datetime). son 4 arrays y 3 variables que no me importan que se repitan. El error que me da cuando quiero insertar los registros con un bucle es que no inserta los registros en la tabla adjunto el nuevo codigo

```
 <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
if (isset($_POST['btncambiar'])) {
    require_once "conexion.php";
    echo '<script>alert("Patente existente") </script>';

    $idmovil = $_POST['idmovil'];
    $fechas = $_POST['fechas'];
    $km = $_POST['km'];

    $fechas = date_create($fechas);
    $fechas = $fechas->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $idestado = $_POST['idestado'];
    $idnivel = $_POST['idnivel'];
    $idobsfila = $_POST['idobsfila'];
    $iditem = $_POST['iditem'];

    // Arreglo de valores
    $values = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($iditem); ++$i) {
        // Con asignación ternaria aseguras que hay un valor
        $item = (isset($iditem[$i])) ? ($iditem[$i]) : 0;
        $estado = (isset($idestado[$i])) ? ($idestado[$i]) : '';
        $nivel = (isset($idnivel[$i])) ? ($idnivel[$i]) : '';
        $obsfila = (isset($idobsfila[$i])) ? ($idobsfila[$i]) : 0;

        // Escapas cadenas
        $estado = $estado;
        $nivel = $nivel;
        $obsfila = $obsfila;

        // Los valores de cadena y fecha deben ir encerrados entre comillas
        $values[] = "($idmovil, $item, '$estado', '$nivel', '$obsfila', '$fechas')";
    }
// Armas la consulta, uniendo los valores con coma y salto de línea
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO checklist VALUES ' . implode(",\n", $values);
    echo $sql;
    // Solo para probar:
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    var_dump($result2);
    
}
```

// este es el echo de $sql y el dump de $result2

INSERT INTO checklist VALUES (57, 28, 'Bueno', 'Mínimo', '', '2020-01-12 12:00:00'), (57, 29, 'Malo', 'Medio', '', '2020-01-12 12:00:00'), (57, 30, 'Malo', 'Máximo', '', '2020-01-12 12:00:00'), (57, 31, 'Malo', 'Medio', '', '2020-01-12 12:00:00'), (57, 32, 'Malo', 'Mínimo', '', '2020-01-12 12:00:00'), (57, 1, 'Bueno', '', 'julio', '2020-01-12 12:00:00'), (57, 2, 'Bueno', '', 'ernesto', '2020-01-12 12:00:00'), (57, 3, 'Malo', '', 'dsakjh', '2020-01-12 12:00:00'), (57, 4, 'Malo', '', 'sdasd', '2020-01-12 12:00:00'), (57, 5, 'Bueno', '', 'dasda', '2020-01-12 12:00:00')bool(false)

//estructura de la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu código podría simplifcarse. ¿Podrías poner un `var_dump($_POST);` y mostrarlo en la pregunta?

Comment: En el `insert into` es recomendable especificar las columnas.

Comment: Por ejemplo el primer valor que es 1 en cada registro, debería incrementarse con el $i +1 del insert y no lo hace

Comment: Ese valor debería ser auto incremental en la base de datos, así no tienes que preocuparte por incrementarlo tú manualmente.

Comment: Es autoincremental pero si quito  el $i+1 del insert se queda pensando y luego me arroja el error sin el valor del campo  id_check (autoincremental) . Tal vez sea porque no lo muestro con el echo   "INSERT INTO checklist   VALUES (" . $idmovil . "," . $iditem[$i] . "," . $idestado[$i] . "," . $idnivel[$i] . "," . $idobsfila[$i] . ", " . $fechas . " )";

Comment: Acabo de editar el codigo y desaparecio el mensaje "Warning: A non-numeric value encountered", quite el $i+1 del insert. Pero me queda el error  Notice: Undefined offset, puede ser que no soporte  que queden campos en blanco ??

Comment: Saludos. Tu `var_dump($iditem);` esta indicando que hay 10 elementos alli; usando `sizeof($iditem)` se asume que deberas llegar de **0**  a **9** en tu `for`; sin embargo los `var_dump` que tienes después indican que no todos tienen 10 elementos; asi que cuando llegas aun `$i` para el cual no existe elemento te marca error. Controla ese escenario como corresponda de manera correcta para ser tratado.

Comment: Creo que tienes razón  RobertoLeOr, porque los arrays $idestado = $_POST['idestado']; $idnivel = $_POST['idnivel']; $idobsfila = $_POST['idobsfila']; no contienen la misma cantidad de elementos. Por ejemplo idnivel tiene 6 elementos para completar en el formulario y el array idestado posee 5 elementos y el array  $idobsfila contiene 9 elementos y el array $iditem son 10. Aunque sigo sin entender porque no lo deja en Null a ese campo donde falta un elemento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código se puede optimizar para ejecutar solo una consulta, simplemente armando los valores adecuados:

- Creas un arreglo para guardar los valores a insertar "(col1, col2, ... colx)"
- En cada iteración del ciclo verificas que las variables estén presentes o, de lo contrario, asignas un valor por defecto, usando asignación ternaria

  - Los elementos numéricos con valor cero si no están presentes
  - Los elementos de cadena con valor de cadena vacía
- Por seguridad, [escapa los elementos de cadena](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), aunque lo ideal es que uses funciones preparadas
- Agrega los valores al arreglo, encerrando entre comillas los elementos de cadena y fecha
- Al terminar el ciclo, completa la consulta y ya puedes ejecutarla

```
// Arreglo de valores
$values = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($iditem); ++$i) {
    // Con asignación ternaria aseguras que hay un valor
    $item = (isset($iditem[$i])) ? $iditem[$i]) : 0;
    $estado = (isset($idestado[$i])) ? $idestado[$i]) : '';
    $nivel = (isset($idnivel[$i])) ? $idnivel[$i]) : '';
    $obsfila = (isset($idobsfila[$i])) ? $idobsfila[$i]) : 0;
    
    // Escapas cadenas
    $estado = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $estado);
    $nivel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $nivel);
    $obsfila = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $obsfila);
    
    // Los valores de cadena y fecha deben ir encerrados entre comillas
    $values[] = "(null, $idmovil, $item, '$estado', '$nivel', '$obsfila', '$fechas')"
}
// Armas la consulta, uniendo los valores con coma y salto de línea
$sql = "INSERT INTO checklist (id_check, Id_Movil, id_servicio, estado, nivel, obser_fila, fecha_rev) VALUES\n" . implode(",\n", $values);

// Solo para probar:
echo $sql;

/* Vas a obtener algo como esto:
INSERT INTO checklist (id_movil, id_servicio, estado, nivel, obser_fila, fecha_rev) VALUES
(57, 28, 'Bueno', 'Mínimo', '', '2020-12-12 12:00:00'),
(57, 28, 'Bueno', 'Mínimo', '', '2020-12-12 12:00:00'),
(57, 28, 'Bueno', 'Mínimo', '', '2020-12-12 12:00:00'),
(57, 28, 'Bueno', 'Mínimo', '', '2020-12-12 12:00:00')
*/
```

**Actualización:** En tu tabla tienes un campo autoincrementable que no se estaba tomando en cuenta, una opción era enviar `null` como valor y, la otra, agregar la lista de campos. Con esto ya debe funcionar.

Agregaría una condición para verificar si `$values` está vacía para no ejecutar la consulta, pero ya es un detalle menor.

Comment: Triby, gracias por tu codigo voy a probarlo ahora mismo!! Ahora que pasa si falta un valor en un registro por ejemplo el valor  Minimo me lo asigna como Null en el campo?

Comment: Perdon Triby, entendi con asignación ternaria si no hay valor en el input del formulario, se insertaria en el campo de la tabla el valor 0 o '' como lo has descripto en el ejemplo?

Comment: Lo segundo, si es numérico se insertará cero, de lo contrario, cadena vacía.

Comment: Perfecto...ahora mismo lo pruebo!

Comment: Triby disculpa, lo único que no puedo hacer es insertar. agregue                  $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); pero no inserta nada

Comment: @Julio, edita la pregunta para agregar el resultado de `echo $sql;`, también de `var_dump($result2);` y la estructura de la tabla.

Comment: Triby recien edito la pregunta, tuve que agregar parentesis en la asignación ternaria porque me tiraba error de sintaxis y mysqli_real_escape_string no me funcionaba el escape, no me traia los datos , una vez que los saque el echo me mostro todos los datos , pero no puedo insertar en la tabla

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta, agregando lista de campos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111250/discussion-between-julio-and-triby).

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que el problema es que no estas difiniendo los nombres de las columnas.
Código actual:

```
 echo "<br>" . "INSERT INTO checklist VALUES (" . $idmovil . "," . $iditem[$i] . "," . $idestado[$i] . "," . $idnivel[$i] . "," . $idobsfila[$i] . ", " . $fechas . " )";
```

Código como deberia ser: Donde dice col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 debes pones el nombre de la columna correspondiente a la posición de los VALUES

```
echo "<br>" . "INSERT INTO checklist ('col1','col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5') VALUES (" . $idmovil . "," . $iditem[$i] . "," . $idestado[$i] . "," . $idnivel[$i] . "," . $idobsfila[$i] . ", " . $fechas . " )";
```